# Tag Rename: lcdscreen -> lcd-screen

Tags: discussion, tags

to make reading tags easier, I propose to swap [lcdscreen](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lcdscreen) to [lcd-screen](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lcd-screen), in line with [x-axis](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-axis) and others.

Comment: Makes sense to me. @0scar should be able to easily make the change, if he wants to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For better readability, the tag has been updated to include a hyphen: [lcd-screen](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lcd-screen).